# Free C# XML Diff library or class

Tags: c#, xml, diff

I’m looking for XML Diff class or library. There are my requirements: 
 - open source :) 
 - object model for output (*)
 - rather fast (for 4mb XML)

I'm trying to use MS XML Diff and Patch Tools, but I wanna get a list of objects with differences of 2 XML files (instead HTML markup).

---

UPD: Thanks for all of your responses. I implemented my own solution; it’s not too hard with Linq2Xml :) 
UPD2: Sorry guys, but i can't post my solution here now (i actually haven't got it because i have changed my work recently). Also my solution have some specific parts, so it can't suit common problems any way. The main advice is to use Linq2Xml, implement your logic and have fun :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research on this topic.

[Tool or library for comparing xml files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547399/tool-or-library-for-comparing-xml-files)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure from you post if you are tring to do this in code or not.

But if you are just after a nice programe to view the two documents side by side and see the difreances and make changes to them i would recomend [Beyond Compare 3](http://www.scootersoftware.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft XML Diff and Patch tool does give you the list of differences between 2 XML document.  The output is an XML document that tells you how to change document #1 into #2.

Comment: Give me objects, don't geve me XMl :) Anyway I already solved my problem