# Diffing large XML files in C# (.net 2.0)

Tags: c#, xml, diff

I'm kind of stuck having to use .Net 2.0, so LINQ xml isn't available, although I would be interested how it would compare...

I had to write an internal program to download, extract, and compare some large XML files (about 10 megs each) that are essentially build configurations. I first attempted using libraries, such as [Microsoft's XML diff/patch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx), but comparing the files was taking 2-3 minutes, even with ignoring whitespace, namespaces, etc. (i tested each ignore one at a time to try and figure out what was speediest). The I tried to implement my own ideas - lists of nodes from XmlDocument objects, dictionaries of keys of the root's direct descendants (45000 children, by the way) that pointed to ints to indicate the node position in the XML document...  all took at least 2 minutes to run.

My final implementation finishes in 1-2 seconds - I made a system process call to diff with a few lines of context and saved those results to display (our development machines include cygwin, thank goodness).

I can't help but think there is a better, XML specific way to do this that would be just as fast as a plain text diff - especially since all I'm really interested in is the Name element that is the child of each direct descendant, and could throw away 4/5 of the file for my purposes (we only need to know what files were included, not anything else involving language or version)

So, as popular as XML is, I'm sure somebody out there has had to do something similar. What is a fast efficient way to compare these large XML's? (prefereably open source or Free)

edit: a sample of the nodes - I only need to find missing Name elements (there are over 45k nodes as well)

```
<file>
     <name>SomeFile</name>
     <version>10.234</version>
     <countries>CA,US</countries>
     <languages>EN</languages>
     <types>blah blah</types>
     <internal>N</internal>
</file>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/655141/102937

Comment: Please provide more context. What kind of output do you need? What kinds of differences are you looking for?

Comment: @Robert Harvey - I already went through that page, no luck

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7973

Comment: @Drake: Well, the conclusion that page came to is that rolling your own solution in Linq to XML is relatively straightforward.  If this is merely a "shopping" question, it's not really on-topic here.

Comment: @Oded - as I stated, I just need to know if there are nodes in one file not in another. Nodes are identified by an element Name, and there are several other elements in the node indicating language, version, etc. that are inconsequential at this time

Comment: Linq in XML is not an option for me - I'm stuck on .Net 2.0

Comment: @DrakeClarris - Are the XML files expected to be "sorted" by nodes? I mean, will a string comparison work for you (as opposed to parsing both files completely before comparing)?

Comment: Yeah they are sorted the same - but no deterministic order from the data available (it depends on dependencies and build order)

Comment: @Angshuman Agarwal - XML notepad took a couple of minutes as well - as far as tools and not program integration (I need to be able to do it within my own program), notepad++ worked much faster than that

Comment: Try this _c:\WINDOWS\system32\fc.exe <XMLFile1> <XMLFile2>_. If this works as per your needs then probably you can invoke this tool programatically.

Comment: What does the XMLs look like, what information is needed?  Linq is good, but it is nowhere close to great when it comes to performance. I suggest that you use Dictionary to index the nodes of interest.

Comment: edited with a sample node - and Angshuman, gotta admit I didn't know that tool was available on windows, but that's the same as using cygwin's diff like I did - although that would be more portable of course. Always learning something new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XmlDocument source = new XmlDocument();
source.Load("source.xml");
Dictionary<string, XmlNode> files = new Dictionary<string, XmlNode>();
foreach(XmlNode file in source.SelectNodes("//file"))
    files.Add(file.SelectSingleNode("./name").InnerText, file);

XmlDocument source2 = new XmlDocument();
source2.Load("source2.xml");
XmlNode value;
foreach(XmlNode file in source2.SelectNodes("//file"))
    if (files.TryGetValue(file.SelectSingleNode("./name").InnerText, out value))
      // This file is both in source and source2.
    else
      // This file is only in source2.
```

I am not sure exactly what you want, I hope that this example will help you in your quest.

Comment: I had tried a dictionary before, but for whatever reason, in my brain, I thought it would be more efficient to store an index to the node list to use (can't really say why, overthinking in the wrong direction I guess). That took a couple of minutes. Gave this a shot - and worked great, nearly as fast as the plain text diff. Don't know why I didn't consider storing a reference to the actual node instead...

Answer (score 0):

Diffing XML can be done many ways. You're not being very specific regarding the details, though. What does transpire is that the files are large and you need only 4/5 of the information.

Well, then the **algorithm** is as follows:

- Normalize and reduce the documents to the information that matters.
- Save the results.
- Compare the results.

And the **implementation**:

- Use the [XmlReader API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx), which is efficient, to produce plain text representations of your information. Why plain text representation? Because diff tools predicated on the assumption that there is plain text. And so are our eyeballs. Why `XmlReader`? You could use SAX, which is memory-efficient, but `XmlReader` is more efficient. As for the precise spec of that plain text file ... you're just not including enough information.
- Save the plain text files to some temp directory.
- Use a command-line diff utility like [GnuWin32 diff](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm) to get some diff output. Yeah, I know, not pure and proper, but works out of the box and there's no coding to be done. If you are familiar with some C# diff API (I am not), well, then use that API instead, of course.
- Delete the temp files. (Or optionally keep them if you're going to reuse them.)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have so far, and it works good, was just hoping for a more "XML" way than plain text diff

Comment: @DrakeClarris, the key insight here is that XML and diff output simply don't match and marry. Which is why it doesn't make sense to hope for a more XML way of doing things. You might just as well hope for a more angular way of rolling wheels.