# How to compare XML documents

Tags: xml, comparison, xmldiff

I need to compare two XML chunks:

```
<elem type="p:type1" xmlns:p="myns" />

<elem type="g:type1" xmlns:g="myns" />
```

They are semantically equivalent once we see that the `type` attribute is QName and not just a string. Is there a tool that can do such a comparison once I provide the schema? Also, is there such an API?

Comment: Oops, now both duplicates have duplicate votes of each other! Please, nobody vote to close this one, do it on the other one.

Comment: This one is a dupe of a lot of other questions, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547399/tool-or-library-for-comparing-xml-files and so should also be closed.

Comment: Okay, both of these should be closed. But the other one should just be deleted. This one should be left for others asking with different words.

Comment: Someone please identify the dupes?  This one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547399/tool-or-library-for-comparing-xml-files is focused on the tool.  This one seems to be focued on programmatically doing the compare.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably many tools that do this, one of them is Xml Diff and Path, via [MS XML downloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/xml/bb190622.aspx)

> The Microsoft XML Diff and Patch
>   utility can be used for comparing two
>   XML documents and then patching the
>   original document with the
>   differences, to create a final
>   document. The utility can detect
>   structural changes (such as the move
>   of an XML subtree) and can create an
>   Xml Diff Language Diffgram (XDL
>   diffgram or just diffgram) that
>   describes the differences between the
>   two XML documents. The diffgram can
>   then be used to display these
>   differences or perform a patch using
>   the XML Patch tool.
>
> XML Diff performs XML-based comparison
>   of the XML documents, as opposed to a
>   common lexical comparison. Therefore,
>   it
>
> Ignores the order attributes. Ignores
>   insignificant white spaces. Does not
>   differentiate between an empty element
>   () and element with no content ().
>   Does not care about the document
>   encoding.

The tools are usable via cmd line and API.

Answer (score 1):

You could download [Xmldiffpatch.exe](http://download.microsoft.com/download/xml/Patch/1.0/WXP/EN-US/xmldiffpatch.exe) tool from the MSDN article "[Using the XML Diff and Patch Tool in Your Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx)"

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile the diff/patch language [XML Patch](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5261) has been specified and deprecated Microsoft XML Diff. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66060336/is-there-rfc-5261-implementation-for-producing-the-xml-patch-files-rather-then) for possible tools. In particular [xmldiff](https://github.com/Shoobx/xmldiff) seems to do proper comparison between XML documents.