# Is there RFC 5261 implementation for producing the XML-patch files (rather then implementations that apply a given patch)

Tags: xml, diff, patch, xmldiff

I've seen a couple of implementation where a RFC 5261 can be applied to a XML file to obtain a new patched version of the original file.
I'm looking for an implementation of RFC 5261 that takes two XML-files and creates the XML-patch that would patch the "a"-file into the "b"-file.

Comment: It should be possible to have a formatter for the xmldiff library ( https://github.com/Shoobx/xmldiff ) to output RFC 5261. We would certainly welcome a PR with that, I doubt I will get time to implement it myself.

I made an issue for it: https://github.com/Shoobx/xmldiff/issues/80