# Compare XML files in Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse

Is there some Eclipse tooling that would allow the comparison of XML files as great as [ExamXML](http://www.a7soft.com/examxml.html) mentioned in this question [Tool or library for comparing xml files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/547399/587642)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diff feature (comparison of two xml file) is very rare in the Eclipse plugin ecosystem (and certainly not there in the [WTP environment](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/sse/)).

I only know about a *commercial* tool, like [`<oXygen/>` XML Diff & Merge](https://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_editor/xml_diff_and_merge.html), which [proposes that](https://www.oxygenxml.com/files_compare_img.html):

[image: link text]
<sub>(source: [oxygenxml.com](http://www.oxygenxml.com/img/compareFilesBig.gif))</sub>

> The diff solution includes two XML diff algorithms (XML Accurate - tuned for precise compare and XML Fast - tuned for speed at the expense of some accuracy), one Syntax Aware algorithm that gives very good results on all file types known by `<oXygen/>` XML Diff and three algorithms that rely on the file structure: line based, word based and character based. Any algorithm can be used to perform differences on request, but `<oXygen/>`  XML Diff offers also an automatic selection, selecting the most appropriate one based on the files' content and size.
>
> The XML diff algorithms are designed to help with the necessities that come with XML document comparison. This means that you can specify if namespaces, prefixes, namespace declarations, processing instructions, comments, CDATA, DOCTYPE, the order of attributes or even text elements should be ignored or not.

[image]