# How can I compare 2 xml files for changed nodes?

Tags: java, xml

I have 2 xml files `a.xml` and `b.xml`, `b.xml` is modified version of `a.xml` where some node values have been changed. Now I want to make a check in my code only particular node values can be changed not all the nodes. How can I make this check in java?
I am getting this xml from user and he is allowed to change only particular nodes if he changes other nodes I should not allow .Below are xml You can see

`<xt:path>HelloWorld/BusinessServices/Mytest</xt:path>` has changed in both this is valid case where as he has also changed

`<xt:value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">40</xt:value>` from 30 to 40 which is not valid.

a.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cus:Customizations xmlns:cus="http://www.bea.com/wli/config/customizations" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xt="http://www.bea.com/wli/config/xmltypes">
  <cus:customization xsi:type="cus:EnvValueCustomizationType">
    <cus:description/>
    <cus:envValueAssignments>
      <xt:envValueType>Service URI Weight</xt:envValueType>
      <xt:location>0</xt:location>
      <xt:owner>
        <xt:type>BusinessService</xt:type>
        <xt:path>HelloWorld/BusinessServices/Test123</xt:path>
      </xt:owner>
      <xt:value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">0</xt:value>
    </cus:envValueAssignments>
    <cus:envValueAssignments>
      <xt:envValueType>Service URI</xt:envValueType>
      <xt:location>0</xt:location>
      <xt:owner>
        <xt:type>BusinessService</xt:type>
        <xt:path>HelloWorld/BusinessServices/Test123</xt:path>
      </xt:owner>
      <xt:value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">jejb:oracle:test</xt:value>
    </cus:envValueAssignments>
    <cus:envValueAssignments>
      <xt:envValueType>Service URI Table</xt:envValueType>
      <xt:location xsi:nil="true"/>
      <xt:owner>
        <xt:type>BusinessService</xt:type>
        <xt:path>HelloWorld/BusinessServices/Test123</xt:path>
      </xt:owner>
      <xt:value>
        <tableElement xmlns="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports">
          <URI>jejb:oracle:test</URI>
          <weight>0</weight>
        </tableElement>
      </xt:value>
    </cus:envValueAssignments>
    <cus:envValueAssignments>
      <xt:envValueType>Service Retry Count</xt:envValueType>
      <xt:location xsi:nil="true"/>
      <xt:owner>
        <xt:type>BusinessService</xt:type>
        <xt:path>HelloWorld/BusinessServices/Test123</xt:path>
      </xt:owner>
      <xt:value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">0</xt:value>
    </cus:envValueAssignments>
    <cus:envValueAssignments>
      <xt:envValueType>Service Retry Iteration Interval</xt:envValueType>
      <xt:location xsi:nil="true"/>
      <xt:owner>
        <xt:type>BusinessService</xt:type>
        <xt:path>HelloWorld/BusinessServices/Test123</xt:path>
      </xt:owner>
      <xt:value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">30</xt:value>
    </cus:envValueAssignments>
  </cus:customization>
  <cus:customization xsi:type="cus:FindAndReplaceCustomizationType">
    <cus:description/>
    <cus:query>
      <xt:resourceTypes>BusinessService</xt:resourceTypes>
      <xt:envValueTypes>Service Retry Iteration Interval</xt:envValueTypes>
      <xt:envValueTypes>Service URI Weight</xt:envValueTypes>
      <xt:envValueTypes>Service Retry Count</xt:envValueTypes>
      <xt:envValueTypes>Service URI</xt:envValueTypes>
      <xt:refsToSearch xsi:type="xt:ResourceRefType">
        <xt:type>BusinessService</xt:type>
        <xt:path>HelloWorld/BusinessServices/Test123</xt:path>
      </xt:refsToSearch>
      <xt:includeOnlyModifiedResources>false</xt:includeOnlyModifiedResources>
      <xt:searchString>Search String</xt:searchString>
      <xt:isCompleteMatch>false</xt:isCompleteMatch>
    </cus:query>
    <cus:replacement>Replacement String</cus:replacement>
  </cus:customization>
  <cus:customization xsi:type="cus:ReferenceCustomizationType">
    <cus:description/>
    <cus:refsToBeConsidered xsi:type="xt:ResourceRefType">
      <xt:type>BusinessService</xt:type>
      <xt:path>HelloWorld/BusinessServices/Test123</xt:path>
    </cus:refsToBeConsidered>
    <cus:externalReferenceMap>
      <xt:oldRef>
        <xt:type>ForeignJNDIProvider</xt:type>
        <xt:path>System/JNDI Providers/oracle</xt:path>
      </xt:oldRef>
      <xt:newRef>
        <xt:type>ForeignJNDIProvider</xt:type>
        <xt:path>System/JNDI Providers/oracle</xt:path>
      </xt:newRef>
    </cus:externalReferenceMap>
    <cus:externalReferenceMap>
      <xt:oldRef>
        <xt:type>Archive</xt:type>
        <xt:path>dev/HelloOsbEjbClient</xt:path>
      </xt:oldRef>
      <xt:newRef>
        <xt:type>Archive</xt:type>
        <xt:path>dev/HelloOsbEjbClient</xt:path>
      </xt:newRef>
    </cus:externalReferenceMap>
  </cus:customization>
</cus:Customizations>
```

b.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cus:Customizations xmlns:cus="http://www.bea.com/wli/config/customizations" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xt="http://www.bea.com/wli/config/xmltypes">
  <cus:customization xsi:type="cus:EnvValueCustomizationType">
    <cus:description/>
    <cus:envValueAssignments>
      <xt:envValueType>Service URI Weight</xt:envValueType>
      <xt:location>0</xt:location>
      <xt:owner>
        <xt:type>BusinessService</xt:type>
        <xt:path>HelloWorld/BusinessServices/Test123</xt:path>
      </xt:owner>
      <xt:value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">0</xt:value>
    </cus:envValueAssignments>
    <cus:envValueAssignments>
      <xt:envValueType>Service URI</xt:envValueType>
      <xt:location>0</xt:location>
      <xt:owner>
        <xt:type>BusinessService</xt:type>
        <xt:path>HelloWorld/BusinessServices/Test123</xt:path>
      </xt:owner>
      <xt:value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">jejb:oracle:test</xt:value>
    </cus:envValueAssignments>
    <cus:envValueAssignments>
      <xt:envValueType>Service URI Table</xt:envValueType>
      <xt:location xsi:nil="true"/>
      <xt:owner>
        <xt:type>BusinessService</xt:type>
        <xt:path>HelloWorld/BusinessServices/Test123</xt:path>
      </xt:owner>
      <xt:value>
        <tableElement xmlns="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports">
          <URI>jejb:oracle:test</URI>
          <weight>0</weight>
        </tableElement>
      </xt:value>
    </cus:envValueAssignments>
    <cus:envValueAssignments>
      <xt:envValueType>Service Retry Count</xt:envValueType>
      <xt:location xsi:nil="true"/>
      <xt:owner>
        <xt:type>BusinessService</xt:type>
        <xt:path>HelloWorld/BusinessServices/Test123</xt:path>
      </xt:owner>
      <xt:value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">0</xt:value>
    </cus:envValueAssignments>
    <cus:envValueAssignments>
      <xt:envValueType>Service Retry Iteration Interval</xt:envValueType>
      <xt:location xsi:nil="true"/>
      <xt:owner>
        <xt:type>BusinessService</xt:type>
        <xt:path>HelloWorld/BusinessServices/Mytest</xt:path>
      </xt:owner>
      <xt:value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">40</xt:value>
    </cus:envValueAssignments>
  </cus:customization>
  <cus:customization xsi:type="cus:FindAndReplaceCustomizationType">
    <cus:description/>
    <cus:query>
      <xt:resourceTypes>BusinessService</xt:resourceTypes>
      <xt:envValueTypes>Service Retry Iteration Interval</xt:envValueTypes>
      <xt:envValueTypes>Service URI Weight</xt:envValueTypes>
      <xt:envValueTypes>Service Retry Count</xt:envValueTypes>
      <xt:envValueTypes>Service URI</xt:envValueTypes>
      <xt:refsToSearch xsi:type="xt:ResourceRefType">
        <xt:type>BusinessService</xt:type>
        <xt:path>HelloWorld/BusinessServices/MyTest</xt:path>
      </xt:refsToSearch>
      <xt:includeOnlyModifiedResources>false</xt:includeOnlyModifiedResources>
      <xt:searchString>Search String</xt:searchString>
      <xt:isCompleteMatch>false</xt:isCompleteMatch>
    </cus:query>
    <cus:replacement>Replacement String</cus:replacement>
  </cus:customization>
  <cus:customization xsi:type="cus:ReferenceCustomizationType">
    <cus:description/>
    <cus:refsToBeConsidered xsi:type="xt:ResourceRefType">
      <xt:type>BusinessService</xt:type>
      <xt:path>HelloWorld/BusinessServices/Test123</xt:path>
    </cus:refsToBeConsidered>
    <cus:externalReferenceMap>
      <xt:oldRef>
        <xt:type>ForeignJNDIProvider</xt:type>
        <xt:path>System/JNDI Providers/oracle</xt:path>
      </xt:oldRef>
      <xt:newRef>
        <xt:type>ForeignJNDIProvider</xt:type>
        <xt:path>System/JNDI Providers/oracle</xt:path>
      </xt:newRef>
    </cus:externalReferenceMap>
    <cus:externalReferenceMap>
      <xt:oldRef>
        <xt:type>Archive</xt:type>
        <xt:path>dev/HelloOsbEjbClient</xt:path>
      </xt:oldRef>
      <xt:newRef>
        <xt:type>Archive</xt:type>
        <xt:path>dev/HelloOsbEjbClient</xt:path>
      </xt:newRef>
    </cus:externalReferenceMap>
  </cus:customization>
</cus:Customizations>
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit ? Provide us with a sample.

Comment: You can parse the XML into a JAXB object and compare those...

Comment: You could always try a tool like [diffxml](http://diffxml.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: For other tools see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547399/tool-or-library-for-comparing-xml-files

Comment: I liked that last link!

Comment: I am looking for java implementation

Comment: My answer (XMLUnit) is for Java

Answer (score 2):

Hmm may you read both files, with the DocumentBuilder. Store the nodes in for example some list that you can compare after reading them:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory fac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = fac.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(new File("a.xml");
```

After that you can get all the nodes out of your document (stored in a NodeList)

```
NodeList list = doc.getElementsbyName("someelement"); //just for an example
```

Hope that I could help you a little

Answer (score 2):

Try [XMLUnit for Java](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/).

> XMLUnit for Java provides two JUnit extension classes, XMLAssert and
> XMLTestCase, and a set of supporting classes (e.g. Diff,
> DetailedDiff,Transform,SimpleXpathEngine,Validator,NodeTest) that
> allow assertions to be made about:
>
> - The differences between two pieces of XML
> - The outcome of transforming a piece of XML using XSLT
> - The evaluation of an XPath expression on a piece of XML
> - The validity of a piece of XML
> - Individual nodes in a piece of XML that are exposed by DOM Traversal
>
>   XMLUnit for Java can also treat HTML content (even badly-formed HTML) as valid XML to allow these assertions to be made about the
>   content of web pages too.

Another DocumentBuilder solution can be found [here](http://jamesfarrugia.blogspot.com.es/2011/12/comparing-two-xml-documents-in-java.html).